# Does Matlab workspace exists when making standalone GUI application?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, simulink, workspace

Does Matlab workspace exists when making standalone GUI application?
I need to make standalone application from GUI and Simulink model.

Data transport from mat file to Simulink is a problem, I  need to know if matlab workspace exists when i make a standalone application from GUI and Simulink?

Comment: How are you making standalone application?

Comment: @Navan I'm guessing he's going to compile it.

Comment: i was planning to make a standalone application from GUI and Simulink model, first i need to compile Simulink model to get an exe file (rsim or grt build method, i'm not sure which is better) then to make data transfer possible between GUI and exe file and then compile all that to one application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't exist in the way that you might be thinking of using it -- i.e. creating data in it, running the simulation (expecting it to load data from the Workspace), then having the simulation save data to it.  That's how simulations work within Simulink, but not within a deployed executable.

Your UI needs to do all its work in Function Workspace's.
Create an RSIM executable, not GRT.
In one of your functions you need to save a .mat file containing the model parameters, and another .mat file containing the model input data.
Then call the RSIM executable using the command line switches to load parameters and inputs from the respective data files, and have it save its data to a specified .mat file.
Then in your (GUI) function you need to load the simulation data from the created output .mat file.

Very messy, but unless you have access to Embedded Coder, and use the dll target that it generates, then the above is the only real option that you have.

Comment: If I use embedded coder can i made a standalone application with simpower blocks?

Comment: Yes, but there are various limitations and restrictions when using Simscape functionality (and associated physical modelling add-ons such as SimPowersystems).  You'll need to do some reading, perhaps starting with [Simscape Code Generation Limitations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ug/limitations.html#bq14bd7-1).